# How to configure MACSEC Key Agreement (MKA) with hostapd & wpasupplicant?

Tags: eap, hostapd, 802.1x, macsec

I'm trying to setup MKA between some clients (using wpa_supplicant) and an authenticator (using hostapd).

Additionally I have a RADIUS server(using FreeRADIUS) that is going to be handling the authentication side of things.

So:

RADIUS server has FreeRADIUS configured for EAP-TLS
Authenticator has hostapd configured with the RADIUS server as auth server
Clients have their client certs & wpasupplicant configured for EAP-TLS

Like this, everything works just fine, and I get the EAP-SUCCESS messages from all sides -

**Auth Server:**

```
(393) Sent Access-Accept Id 37 from 10.0.0.254:1812 to 10.0.0.250:42690 length 252
```

**Authenticator:**

```
EAP: EAP entering state SUCCESS2
br0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS2 8e:43:b5:ca:b6:f2
IEEE 802.1X: 8e:43:b5:ca:b6:f2 BE_AUTH entering state SUCCESS
br0: STA 8e:43:b5:ca:b6:f2 IEEE 802.1X: Sending EAP Packet (identifier 236)
IEEE 802.1X: 8e:43:b5:ca:b6:f2 AUTH_PAE entering state AUTHENTICATED
br0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 8e:43:b5:ca:b6:f2
br0: STA 8e:43:b5:ca:b6:f2 IEEE 802.1X: authorizing port
br0: STA 8e:43:b5:ca:b6:f2 RADIUS: starting accounting session 1F1E651F858DB876
br0: RADIUS Sending RADIUS message to accounting server
br0: RADIUS Next RADIUS client retransmit in 3 seconds
```

**client:**

```
eth0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully
```

As far as I understand it, this is the prerequisite for MKA, where a keyserver generates the keys and sends them to the authenticator to establish the MACSEC connection, which is what I want to happen next.

So in the FreeRADIUS directory on the server I edit the `sites-available/default` file and uncomment this section:

```
        #  MacSEC requires the use of EAP-Key-Name.  However, we don't
        #  want to send it for all EAP sessions.  Therefore, the EAP
        #  modules put required data into the EAP-Session-Id attribute.
        #  This attribute is never put into a request or reply packet.
        #
        #  Uncomment the next few lines to copy the required data into
        #  the EAP-Key-Name attribute
        if (&reply:EAP-Session-Id) {
                update reply {
                        EAP-Key-Name := &reply:EAP-Session-Id
                }
        }
```

After which I see the key material being successfully received by hostapd on the authenticator:

```
MS-MPPE-Send-Key - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
MS-MPPE-Recv-Key - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
EAP-Key Name - hexdump(len=65): 0d 4b f6 4e 19 d1 af 12 86 6a ff 30 a4 48 44 f4 4c c3 51 a8 bf d4 2c ce f5 d7 2b d4 b9 d1 4d 32 bc d6 50 82 bc 19 70 4b 39 11 96 f6 d1 fb 53 ec 16 a6 2d 89 39 8b c3 78 a2 e4 31 f4 39 95 d7 d3 bf
```

However there didn't seem to be anything else happening after this point. I thought I had to change the config files to enforce MACSEC, so on the Client I edited the **wpa_supplicant.conf** file to add `macsec_policy=1` in the network configuration, but alone doesn't seem to trigger anything, so I thought maybe I need to configure hostapd too.

However when I add `macsec_policy=1` to **hostapd.conf** on the Authenticator, hostapd doesn't recognize the option:

```
Line 39: unknown configuration item 'macsec_policy'
1 errors found in configuration file '/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'
Failed to set up interface with /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
hostapd_init: free iface 0x55a72992bbf0
Failed to initialize interface
```

What do I need to do to enforce that a macsec channel be created between the authenticator and clients?

I feel like I'm close since the key material is being received by hostapd, but not sure how to complete the configuration. I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035836/macsec-interface-using-wpa-supplicant-802-1x-2010) old question here that shows a sample wpa_supplicant.conf file, which looks more or less like what I have, but he doesn't mention what he has configured at the authenticator side.